# Real-world progress bar

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

#### Backstory, skip if you like

Generating high quality pseudo random numbers is a tricky business but the fine engineers at < enter company you love to hate > have mastered it. Their progress bars effortlessly rise above the primitive notion of linearly passing time and add an exhilarating sense of unpredictability to the waiting experience.

Cynics have dismissed the entire matter as a ploy to prevent employees from being able to assess whether there is enough time to grab a coffee. All I can say is I feel sorry for those people.

It so happens that your boss believes to have reverse-engineered the secret of the  < enter company you love to hate > (tm) progress bar and has tasked you with golfing up a simulator.

#### Task

Given a length L and list of tasks, each represented by a list of times each of the task's steps is expected to take, implement a progress bar that at each time indicates the percentage of steps expected to have completed by that time assuming the tasks are independent. The length of the bar should be L at 100%.

#### I/O

Flexible within reason. You may pass list lengths separately if you wish.

You may also input a time in which case the output should be a single horizontal bar of correctly rounded integer length.

Otherwise you may represent time as actual time in a unit of your choice or  as one axis (top-to-bottom) in a 2D plot.

#### Examples

```
I: [20,[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[10]]

O:

###
######
#########
#########
##############
##############
##############
#################
####################

I: [8,[1,1],[2,1],[3,2],[12,1]]

O:
#
###
#####
#####
######
######
######
######
######
######
######
#######
########

I: [30,[1,2,3],[2,4,7],[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],[9,10],[1,1,3,2]]

O:
###
########
#########
###########
############
#################
##################
####################
#####################
#######################
#######################
########################
##########################
###########################
###########################
#############################
#############################
#############################
##############################

I: [4.7,20,[1,2,3],[10,10],[1,1,1],[4,10]]

O:
############
```

#### Scoring/rules/loopholes:

code-golf as usual.

#### Reference implementation Python >= 3.8

```python
def f(l,S,c=0):
 T=len(sum(S,[]))            # total number of steps
 while S:=[*filter(None,S)]: # check whether any tasks still runnimg
  for s in S:                # go through tasks
   if s[0]>1:s[0]-=1         # current step terminating? no: update time left
   else:c+=s.pop(0)	     # yes: remove step and increment step counter
  print((T//2+l*c)//T*"#")   # output bar
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7BbsIwEETP5StWcLHBLQEuVaS0f9BLuEU5pGaTWDhry1634utTA1WFuntYaTXzZvyFR0eHVx/m@YQ99MKqWumqkOUCjpVFEjFNolZNKyU8zArYcWeB0vSJAVwPkdHHBXyPxiLUZdWse2MZg/hwhKqWbZlNekR9zhrkMbs6ugB38Ryz2VgLIRGZaVgA9C5ABEMZBP9mBYMDHoNLw3h3Zz2YXKAp2rddeT3P1e5Br1MISHxrCLnRZKhjQ8M7kCsh@VPHCGwmBIs9X2loI5Z6U8UX77wo5NMv6YKxhICT@8I7raNTbqnz6y9Au0Q5JGN8MMRCHLfb/cautdxuj@vlailvKJfYJ4bPLsy92BcKmmav8raqOai8@e6KtpXzDw)

Comment: Can we assume all inputs are non-empty and non-zero?

Comment: How do we deal with rounding issues?

Comment: Yes, you can. Round to the nearest integer, upwards in case of ties.

Comment: It is unclear to me what determines the number of rows in your 2D box plots. Can you explain?

Comment: Assuming I didn't mess up it should be one row per time unit. So the height in lines is the total number of time units the longest task will take to complete.

Comment: What does the last case mean?

Comment: It shows the three-argument (time,max_length,tasks) option. Output is s snapshot at time.

Comment: I find the challenge description confusing. So each *task* has a number of *steps*, and the progress bar represents how many *steps* have been completed (out of the total number of steps for all tasks)? Does the number associated with each step affect how much of the progress bar is filled in by the completion of that step, or does it only affect when the step is completed? Are the tasks completed one after the other (in series), or at the same time (in parallel)? And what do pseudo-random numbers have to do with it?

Comment: If step duration would enter into the bar increment and the tasks were in series the bar would essentially grow linear in time, so no to both.

Comment: Could you actually illustrate how you arrive at the "progress" in each step, wtih a show of calculation? For eg. why there's 3 #'s in the first line of the first output, then 5 in the second line. Instead of explaining with words (which is obviously failing to reach some of us including me), just show us the arithmetic for one example.

Comment: Added reference implementation.

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 16 bytes

```
ƛ¦Þǔ;∑¦Ḣ:G/*⌈×*⁋
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLGm8Kmw57HlDviiJHCpuG4ojpHLyrijIjDlyrigYsiLCIiLCJbWzEsMiwzXSxbMiw0LDddLFsyLDIsMiwyLDIsMiwyLDJdLFs5LDEwXSxbMSwxLDMsMl1dXG4zMCJd)

Straightforward port of [my Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242782/100664), go see that explanation for a better idea of how it works. Jelly has some nicer builtins.

```
ƛ   ;            # Map each task to...
 ¦               # Cumulative sums (instants where a step will complete)
  Þǔ             # Untruth (a boolean list with 1s at those indices)
     ∑           # Reduce the whole thing by addition
      ¦Ḣ         # Get cumulative sums and remove the leading zero
        :G/      # Divide by the maximum
           *     # Multiply by the input
            ⌈    # Get the ceiling
             ×*⁋ # Make a bar graph
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but is it really not possible to output an actual ASCII bar with those golfy golf languages? I mean, it is part of the task.

Comment: @loopywalt [It is](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLGm8Kmw57HlDviiJHCpuG4ojpHLyrijIjDlyrigYsiLCIiLCJbWzEsMiwzXSxbMiw0LDddLFsyLDIsMiwyLDIsMiwyLDJdLFs5LDEwXSxbMSwxLDMsMl1dXG4zMCJd), but it's shorter not to. I assumed a list of integers was a reasonable output format, but if it's not I can change this.

Comment: In that case I would say you should output bars. Considering the whole challenge is literally about _progress bars_ that seems only fair to me.

Comment: @loopywalt Okay.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 91 bytes

```python
lambda L,X,t:int(sum((s:=0)+sum(t>=(s:=s+y)for y in x)for x in X)*L/sum(map(len,X))+.5)*'#'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1RCoMwEESvstAPs7q0RikUwZ7AAwSsHynVNqAxJCno6VO3zMe8gQfj9vhZbX1zPk3tI816eb40dKQoNsZGEb6LEKFpSywY473lFYodp9XDDsbC9seNUWHeXdhbtBPzaEkhFucr5tkpS2wZtry271FIkhIbcJ5vJlGVBH1f0ZGB@pqOHC3LYSAwiOkH)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) with [numpy](https://numpy.org/), 76 bytes

```python
lambda L,X,t:int(L*mean(t>=hstack(map(cumsum,X)))+.5)*'#'
from numpy import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxBDoIwEEDRvaeYxAUdnBgKcUOCJ@AAJMiiIpVGp21Ku@D0FfMWf/f9Hldnm6y7R/4qfr4U9DRQbI2Noi95UVbEe7duUc0fwcqLOfGWmAZEvFxvWBbn4qSDY7CJ/Q6GvQuxzNoFMGAsBGXfi5AkJbbgw/@rRV0RjGNNh4nGhg5HZTVNBAYx/wA)

`cumsum` transforms a list of step lengths into an array of the steps' finishing times, and `hstack` combines those arrays into one long array. The comparison produces 1 for finished steps and 0 for unfinished steps, and then `mean` gives the proportion of finished steps.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 32 bytes

```
Ｅ⌈ＥηΣι⁺·⁵∕×ΣＥηΣＥλ¬›Σ…λ⊕ξ⊕ιθΣＥηＬλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU3BCsIwFPuVHlt4ypx48jhBBJXBvJUeyvawhbbTrhvz62tXBJXweCEJSaukb3tpYqy9doFe5CPdrO1oM1dAmkQ1YwxIbcaBFusdkIOedIf0pi0OtPnPLtQAufaBHj3KgD4nqldrsFJ9Nk@u9WjRBezonLt/lWWNZfXJvp2p/ozuHhQ1H38fIy8L4LyEBAF8CwnpbwohRFxN5g0) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a bar graph. Explanation:

```
   η                                List of tasks
  Ｅ                                 Map over elements
     ι                              Current list of subtasks
    Σ                               Take the sum
 ⌈                                  Take the maximum
Ｅ                                   Map over implicit range
             η                      List of tasks
            Ｅ                       Map over elements
                λ                   Current list of subtasks
               Ｅ                    Map over elements
                     λ              Current list of subtasks
                    …               Truncated to length
                       ξ            Innermost index
                      ⊕             Incremented
                   Σ                Take the sum
                 ¬›                 Is less then or equal to
                         ι          Outer value
                        ⊕           Incremented
              Σ                     Take the sum
           Σ                        Take the sum
          ×                         Multiplied by
                          θ         Desired maximum length
         ∕                          Divided by
                             η      List of tasks
                            Ｅ       Map over elements
                               λ    Current list of subtasks
                              Ｌ     Take the length
                           Σ        Take the sum
      ⁺                            Plus
       ·⁵                          Literal number `0.5`
                                   Implicitly print as bar graph
```

35 bytes for a version that outputs in real time:

```
ＲＦφ⌈ＥηΣιＰ⁺·⁵∕×ΣＥηΣＥκ¬›Σ…κ⊕ν⊕ιθΣＥηＬκ
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
ÄṬSÄ÷Ṁ$×+.ḞṬ€G
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wy8Oda4IPtxze/nBng8rh6dp6D3fMAwo9alrj/j862lDHSMc4VifaSMdExxxMo0CgiKWOoQGQMtQx1DEGCsQeXm5s8B8A)

A dyadic link that outputs a bar graph (sorta).

I'm quite proud of `ÄṬSÄ` which generates the numbers before stretching. I'm also somewhat annoyed that the code to stretch the numbers is six bytes. I feel like there's got to be a better way to do that, but I'm not sure what.

The below explanation uses `[[1,1],[2,1],[3,2],[4,1]]` and `16` as an example.

```
Ä               Take the cumulative sums of each item
                Generating a list of lists of indices at which another task segment completes.
                For the example list, [[1,2],[2,3],[3,5],[4,5]]
 Ṭ              Take the untruth of each item
                Turning each into a boolean list with 1s at the specified indices
                Each task is now a boolean list where 1s represent that a task will be represented at that instant
                For the example, [[1,1],[0,1,1],[0,0,1,0,1],[0,0,0,1,1]]
  S             Reduce the list by vectorised addition
                The result becomes a single list where the number at each index
                Is the number of tasks completed at that instant
                [1,2,2,1,2]
   Ä            Take the cumulative sum, getting the total tasks completed at that instant
                [1,3,5,6,8]
    --$         Run what's next on the result of the above
    ÷           Float divide the list by...
     Ṁ          Its maximum
                Producing a list of floats between 0 and 1
                [.125,.375,.625,.875,1]
       ×        Multiply the result of the above by the other input
        +.Ċ     Round the results.
                [2,6,10,14,16]
           Ṭ€G  Format into a grid
```

Comment: Can `µ÷Ṁð` -> `÷Ṁ$`

Comment: @UnrelatedString Thanks!

Comment: Why are you getting the ceiling of the result? The question specifies rounding.

Comment: @Neil Oh, okay.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 85 bytes

```r
\(L,x)barplot(sapply(max(u<-unlist(Map(cumsum,x))):1,\(i)(.5+mean(u<=i)*L)%/%1),ho=T)
```

[Try it on rdrr.io!](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=f%3Dfunction(L%2Cx)barplot(sapply(max(u%3C-unlist(Map(cumsum%2Cx)))%3A1%2Cfunction(i)(.5%2Bmean(u%3C%3Di)*L)%25%2F%251)%2Cho%3DT)%0A%0Af(20%2Clist(c(2%2C2%2C2)%2Cc(3%2C3%2C3)%2C10))%0Af(8%2Clist(c(1%2C1)%2C2%3A1%2C3%3A2%2Cc(12%2C1)))%0Af(30%2Clist(c(1%2C2%2C3)%2Cc(2%2C4%2C7)%2Crep(2%2C8)%2C9%3A10%2Cc(1%2C1%2C3%2C2)))) with graphical output, but with older and longer function syntax.